# Missing Nuget packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I just got back to an old project of mine and I noticed I had some nuget packages I have to restore, which I've had in the past but than I could go to the console and it would ask me if I wanted to restore my packages. 
And the times I haven't gotten that prompt I could always run this command `Update-Package –reinstall`

How ever none of this solves my problem, the packages I am missign are:

```
EntityFramework
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.WebPages
```

Comment: So what *does* happen if you try to restore those packages?

Comment: `"none of this solves my problem"` - Perhaps I missed it, but what *is* the problem exactly?

Comment: I just run the command I did post above I get this No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'MyTestProject'.

Comment: @David the packages doesn't get restored.

Comment: Try -> nuget restore Solution.sln

Comment: @user3134635 he term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correc
t and try again.

Comment: try and right click on your solution and hit Enable Nuget Package Restore

Comment: You have to enable Nuget Package Restore for your project. If that is not working then locate .nuget folder. In windows command line change the directory to .nuget folder of your project and then run above command. You have to specify the full path of your .sln file.

Comment: @Prime03 I do not have Enable Nuget Package Restore for some reason, User3134634 i'll try that.

Comment: @ssakash I forgot to post back, but that did work for me. Post it as an answear and i'll accept it asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable Nuget Package Restore for your project. If that is not working then locate .nuget folder. In windows command line change the directory to .nuget folder of your project and then run

```
nuget restore Solution.sln
```

You have to specify the full path of your .sln file.